# Howto add a new role with a custom permission set for Solidus / Spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming, spree

I want to add a new 'vendor' role. 
A vendor can manage his own products and orders, but not see any orders or products belonging to an other vendor.

I was planning to implement this around the Stock Location. 
E.g: One user with the vendor role belongs to the Tokyo stock location. An other user with the vendor role belongs to an other stock location.

Which steps need to me taken to get this working?

Comment: It's always good to try to answer a question that needs answering. Please provide a better title as it's not indicative of the problem. "HOWTO create a custom role with a custom permission set." would be better but use "How to create a custom role with a custom permission set." It's not necessary to use your first paragraph at all and I'd recommend removing it. Also, your format is wrong. Ask the question, then, in an answer provide the solution. Don't put it all in the question. Stack Overflow will then let you select your answer.

Comment: I agree. Thanks for the input.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1.  Create a vendor role

```
$ rails console
Spree::Role.create(name: 'vendor')
```

#### 2. Define CanCan permissions:

*app/models/spree/multi_vendor_ability.rb*

```
module Spree
  class MultiVendorAbility
    include CanCan::Ability

    def initialize(user)
      user ||= Spree::User.new # guest user (not logged in)
      if user.admin?
        can :manage, :all
        puts "IS admin"
      else
        can :read, :all
        puts "NOT admin"
      end

      if user.stock_locations.present?
        can  :manage, Spree::StockItem, :stock_location_id => user.stock_locations.first.id
      end
    end

  end
end
```

#### 3. Add a new method to Spree::User

*config/initializers/spree_user.rb*

```
Spree::User.class_eval do

    def vendor?
      self.role_users.any? { |ru| ru.role.name == 'vendor' }
    end

end
```

#### 4. RSpec

*spec/models/multi_vendor_spec.rb*

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Spree::MultiVendorAbility do
  let(:ability) { Spree::MultiVendorAbility.new(user) }
  let(:user)    { create(:user) }
  let(:product) { create :product }
  let(:stock_location) { create(:stock_location_with_items) }
  let(:stock_item) { stock_location.stock_items.order(:id).first }

  subject { ability }

  context "test" do
    before do
      Rails.logger.debug "The StockItem is #{stock_item.inspect}"
      user.stock_locations = [stock_location]
      user.save
    end

    context "when the user is associated with the stock location" do
       it { is_expected.to be_able_to(:manage,  Spree::StockItem) }
    end

    context "when the user is NOT associated with the stock location" do
        before do
          stock_item.stock_location_id = nil
          stock_item.save
          user.stock_locations = []
          user.save
          puts "The StockItem is #{stock_item.inspect}"
          user.stock_locations = []
        end
        it { is_expected.to_not be_able_to(:manage, Spree::StockItem) }
    end

  end

end
```

Comment: I'm not seeing app/models/spree/multi_vendor_ability.rb in solidus_auth_devise or solidus.

Comment: No, that's a file you add to _your_ Rails app. :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe in Solidus you would create a PermissionSet, and in your Spree/Solidus initializer you would assign that new role the permission set. You can avoid all the if/then/elses and easily store multiple roles with overlapping permission sets this way.